# Combobox returning null when it's not?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following `if` statement:

```
If line.Contains(":") And Not line.Contains(removeCombo.SelectedItem) Then
                    file2.WriteLine(line)
                End If
```

In this instance, `removeCombo` is the combobox and the variable `line` is the current line in a file. The `if` statement returns:

> 'Value Cannot Be Null.'

Why is this? I have also chosen a value in the combobox.

Comment: maybe there is nothing selected in `removecombo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing:

```
   removeCombo.SelectedItem
```

with:

```
removeCombo.Text
```

Comment: You're welcome. Mark as answer and upvote since it solved your problem. Thanks :)